# Pattern matching an array

Tags: arrays, pattern-matching

I've created a:

```
 newType Board = Board (Array (Int, Int) Life)
```

, where

```
 data Life = Alive|Dead
```

Im trying to make a function to save the board to a String by pattern matching:

```
showBoard:: Config -> String
showBoard Board(array ((0, 0), (w, h)) [(a:as)]) = *code*
```

But this only gives me "Parse error in pattern: array". I cant see what's wrong?

Comment: `Array` is a type constructor; what does its data constructor look like?

Comment: Im using the Data.Array library

Comment: `array` is a function that returns an `Array` value, but it is not a data constructor. `Data.Array` does not appear to export any data constructors, so you cannot do pattern matching on those values.

Answer (score 4):

You can only pattern-match on data constructors. `array` is not a data constructor; it is a regular function that internal uses the `Array` data constructor(s) to create and return an `Array` value. The internal details
of an `Array` are not exposed, preventing you from pattern-matching on them.

Instead, you need use the functions provided for looking at an `Array` value. These can be composed with a function that *does* take arguments you can pattern match on.

```
-- bounds :: Array i e -> (i, i)
-- elems :: Array i e -> [e]
showConfig :: Board -> String
showConfig (Board arr) = showConfig' (bounds arr) (elems arr)
  where showConfig' :: ((Int,Int),(Int,Int)) -> [Life] -> String
        showConfig' ((0,0),(w,h)) (a:as) = ...
```

If you modify your `Board` type to

```
newtype Board = Board { getArray :: Array (Int, Int) Life }
```

you can rewrite `showConfig` in an applicative style:

```
showConfig = (showConfig' <$> boards <*> elems) . getArray
  where showConfig' ((0,0),(w,h)) (a:as) = ...
```